# dovecot+exim configuration, error while restarting exim

Tags: dovecot, exim

When I try to configure Dovecot together with Exim, I get an error
while restarting Exim:

```
Exim configuration error in line 63 of /etc/exim/exim.conf:
  main option "dovecot_login" unknown
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It clearly states that in the `exim.conf` file, specifically line 63, the option `dovecot_login` doesn't exist. Double check that the version of exim supports that configuration item.

Comment: installed version is Exim version 4.72, it supports dovecot.

Comment: Let me say it again, make sure it supports that configuration item. The one I highlighted which is `dovecot_login`

Comment: sorry for the trouble i will check it...

Comment: Just a friendly note, no one will be able to help you with barely an error message, all we get from it is that you used an unknown option.

Comment: The directive seems to be misplaced. I suppose it should be in the section started with `begin authenticators`.

Comment: You'll need to have an "authenticator" mechanism for 'dovecot_login'. It is hard to diagnose the issue from the little information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you were following the Debian HOWTO at https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/EximAndDovecotSASL, as I just did.

nowadays Debian uses exim4, and exim.conf doesn't exist, and would be ignored if it did.

the reason `dovecot_login` is unknown is because exim4 isn't prepared for it: the keywords `begin authenticators` must precede it in the configuration. if you're using the "split" configuration mode, as is typical for more complex installations, this could be accomplished by placing the file, perhaps named 05_dovecot, under /etc/exim4/conf.d/auth, which has the magic incantation in 00_exim4-config_header.

update-exim4.conf will process the files under conf.d/auth/ in lexical order, and it will ignore the pre-existing file "dovecot.conf" in that directory (because it ignores any file with a dot in it) and see 05_dovecot after 00_exim4-config_header.